# How to scroll iframe from parent window using window.postMessage?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, scroll

Does `window.Postmessage` need any website permission to communication between windows/frames hosted on different domains?

If not how to achieve scrolling of iframe?

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolling of iframe"?

Comment: Please explain your issue in proper detail. See [ask]

Comment: I have nav bar with one link clicking on that iframe need to scroll to 1000 pixel offset